# How to optimize my R script in order to use "multicore"

Tags: r

I am using GNU R at a Ubuntu-Lucid PC which has 4 CPUs.
In order to use all 4 CPUs, I installed the "r-cran-multicore" package.
As the package's manual lacks of practical examples that I understand, I need advice in how to optimize my script in order to make use of all 4 CPUs.

My dataset is a data.frame (called P1) that has 50,000 rows and 1600 cols. For each row, I'd like to calc the maximun, sum and mean. My script looks as follows:

```
p1max <- 0
p1mean <- 0
p1sum <-0
plength <- length(P1[,1])
for(i in 1:plength){
   p1max <- c(p1max, max(P1[i,]))
   p1mean <- c(p1mean, mean(P1[i,]))
   p1sum <- c(p1sum, sum(P1[i,]))
}
```

Could anyone please tell me how to modify and run the script in order to use all 4 CPUs?

Comment: there's an error in the above program: the line should be "for(i in 1:plength)"

Comment: you are rigth, thx!

Comment: doesn't this belong on StackOverflow?

Comment: This does belong on StackOverflow. There's no statistics question here at all. Only a general programming question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [foreach](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/index.html) and [doMC](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doMC/index.html). The detailed explanation can be [found here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doMC/vignettes/gettingstartedMC.pdf). Your script will change very little, the line

```
for(i in 1:plength){
```

should be changed to

```
foreach(i=1:plength) %dopar% {
```

The prerequisites for any multitasking script using these packages are

```
library(foreach)
library(doMC)
registerDoMC()
```

Note of caution. According to the documentation you cannot use this in GUI.

As for your problem, do you really need multitasking? Your data.frame takes about 1.2GB of RAM, so it should fit into your memory. So you can simply use apply:

```
p1smry <- apply(P1,1,summary)
```

The result will be a matrix with summaries of each row.

You can also use function **mclapply** which is in the package multicore. Then your script might look like this:

```
loopfun <- function(i) {
     summary(P1[i,])
}

res <- mclapply(1:nrow(P1),loopfun)
```

This will return the list, where i-th element will be the summary of i-th row. You can convert it to matrix using **sapply**

```
mres <- sapply(res,function(x)x)
```

Comment: thank you very much. You are right, that with "apply" the script could be optimized. I just used my script as a minimal-example in order to get the message through... Thx a lot, your answer is exactly what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 15):

You've already got an answer as to how to use more than one core, but the real problem is with the way you have written your loops. **Never extend your result vector/object at each iteration of a loop**. If you do this, you force R to copy your result vector/object and extend it which all takes time. Instead, preallocate enough storage space before you start the loop and fill in as you go along. Here is an example:

```
set.seed(1)
p1 <- matrix(rnorm(10000), ncol=100)
system.time({
p1max <- p1mean <- p1sum <- numeric(length = 100)
for(i in seq_along(p1max)){
   p1max[i] <- max(p1[i,])
   p1mean[i] <- mean(p1[i,])
   p1sum[i ]<- sum(p1[i,])
}
})

   user  system elapsed 
  0.005   0.000   0.005
```

Or you can do these things via `apply()`:

```
system.time({
p1max2 <- apply(p1, 1, max)
p1mean2 <- apply(p1, 1, mean)
p1sum2 <- apply(p1, 1, sum)
})
   user  system elapsed 
  0.007   0.000   0.006
```

But note that this is **no** faster than doing the loop properly and sometimes slower.

However, always be on the lookout for vectorised code. You can do row sums and means using `rowSums()` and `rowMeans()` which are quicker than either the loop or `apply` versions:

```
system.time({
p1max3 <- apply(p1, 1, max)
p1mean3 <- rowMeans(p1)
p1sum3 <- rowSums(p1)
})

   user  system elapsed 
  0.001   0.000   0.002
```

If I were a betting man, I would have money on the third approach I mention beating `foreach()` or the other multi-core options in a speed test on your matrix because they would have to speed things up considerably to justify the overhead incurred in setting up the separate processes that are farmed out the the different CPU cores.

Update: Following the comment from @shabbychef is it faster to do the sums once and reuse in the computation of the mean?

```
system.time({
    p1max4 <- apply(p1, 1, max)
    p1sum4 <- rowSums(p1)
    p1mean4 <- p1sum4 / ncol(p1)
    })

   user  system elapsed 
  0.002   0.000   0.002
```

Not in this test run, but this is far from exhaustive...

Comment: FWIW, Matlab has the same issues regarding preallocation and expanding vectors, and is a classic code 'blooper'. In addition to your wager, it is probably faster to use the results of `rowSums` to compute the row means (unless I am missing something regarding _e.g._ Na or NaN). The code in your third approach sums each column *twice*.

Comment: @shabbychef you'll be surprised (see my edited answer). Yes the sums are notionally computed twice, but `rowSums` and `rowMeans` are highly optimised compiled code and what we gain in only computing the sums once, we loose again in doing the mean computation in interpreted code.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson: not so fast: try instead `system.time({
 for (iii in c(1:1000)) {
 p1max3 <- apply(p1, 1, max)
 p1mean3 <- rowMeans(p1)
 p1sum3 <- rowSums(p1)
 }
})` and similarly `system.time({
 for (iii in c(1:1000)) {
  p1max4 <- apply(p1, 1, max)
    p1sum4 <- rowSums(p1)
    p1mean4 <- p1sum4 / ncol(p1)
 }
})`; the version which does not recompute the sum takes 1.368 seconds on my computer; the one which does takes 1.396. again, far from exhaustive, but more compelling...

Comment: @shabbychef we must have different ideas on what is or is not compelling ;-) In fact, your more rigorous simulations reinforce my main point, that as `rowMeans` and `rowSums` are implemented in efficient, optimised compiled code they are going to be difficult to beat.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson. Actually, the problem with my example is that most of the time is taken in the apply part to compute the maximum. I agree with you that a c-based vectorized function like `rowMean` is going to be hard to beat via a general-purpose R tool like `*apply`. However, you seem to suggest that it is faster to sum 10000 numbers *twice* via `rowMean` and `rowSum` rather than only once and use R's builtin division operator. I know R has some efficiency issues (_e.g._ the recent discovery of the curly braces vs. parenthesis issue), but that seems crazy.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson: as a followup, try the following: 
p1 <- matrix(rnorm(10000), ncol=100)

system.time({
 for (iii in c(1:20000)) {
    p1sum5 <- rowSums(p1)
    p1mean5 <- p1sum5 / ncol(p1)
 }
})

system.time({
 for (iii in c(1:20000)) {
    p1sum6 <- rowSums(p1)
    p1mean6 <- rowMeans(p1)
 }
})

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [snow](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/snow/index.html) and [snowfall](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/snowfall/index.html) packages. Plenty of examples with those...

If you want to speed up that specific code rather than learning about R and parallelism you should do this

```
P1 = matrix(rnorm(1000), ncol=10, nrow=10
apply(P1, 1, max)
apply(P1, 1, mean)
apply(P1, 1, sum)
```

Comment: please help me to modify my script...

Comment: Those are just hiding the loop from you. The real problem with @Produnis code is that forced copying is going on because the results vectors are being extended at each iteration of the loop.

Comment: snowfall package can extend Gavin's solution like saying "cake". Package has a plethora of apply function modified to do multicoring. For apply function, you would use sfApply(<yourarguments as for apply>). Snowfall is also well documented. I should point out that no extra software is needed for performing this on a multi-core processor. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164960/which-list-element-is-being-processed-when-using-snowfallsflapply for a sfLapply example.